# While logging a payment transaction, should i use id's of tables or directly the values

Tags: mysql, database, logging

i want to log all payment transactions. but i cant decide if i should store the id leading to the value or directly the value itself. if i store the id's of values then i have to store the values as long as the log exists. but if i store the values alone then i could have problems on tracking the informations. which way do you think could be more healty?

```
ACCOUNT TABLE
id title
0  Color Inc
1  Farbe Gmbh

USER TABLE
id name surname
1  joe  zimmermann
2  hans black

LOG TABLE
id user_id account_id amount
0  1       0          330
1  2       1          10
```

in this example above i store the id's of the values.

```
LOG TABLE
id user_name account_title amount
0  joe       Color Inc     330
1  hans      Farbe Gmbh     10
```

Here i logged the values directly. So what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of transactions (like a virtual pos terminal on a web page), I find it better to log everything I can. For example: Timestamp, direction, amount, type of transaction, partnerid, id of the invoice or other certificate which connected to the transaction.

These kind of stuff, where you can't make any mistake, or if you do, you have to be able to trace back everything. So I recommend saving a reasonable amount of data for each and every transactions.